# Best practice for a large liststore updated in realtime

Tags: listview, debugging, gtk, code-editor

I am currently coding a code editor and want to add debugger functionality, which should show a list of the codes variables with their values. This list should get updated in realtime. I have access to the programs memory, so I can retrieve the values with pointers.

I was thinking about using a `GtkListStore` for this, but wouldn't this need too much memory? I can't see a way to pass the variables pointers to the list, so I would have to copy the values to the list instead (which is rather slow aswell).

In a perfect world, I would do this (pseudocode):

```
y = 0
for var in variable
    showText(x, y++, var->name, *var->pointer)
    if y > listWindowSize break
end
```

I wouldn't have to manually update the list, since it's using the values retrieved from the pointers. Is this somehow possible with GTK or is there a better way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data structures and want to have a GtkTreeView as view of your data it's best to implement a custom GtkTreeModel. It's not hard and I have done this myself for a project in the past. There is a very valuable tutorial here: http://scentric.net/tutorial/treeview-tutorial.html. In particular, read chapter 11, where it explains how to write a custom GtkTreeModel.